# RDS/RDP : Connection reset by client on one network

Tags: rdp, rds

I have an issue with RDS access on ONE network only (assuming 10.10.0.0/24)
It give me "crendetials didn't work" message just after log in.

RDS access is ok all other networks (10.10.3.0/24 and 10.40.0.0 for example).
When i connect to server 10.10.0.16 from VMWare Console, i can RDS other servers in 10.10.0.0/24.
NLA is activated for ALL networks.

My client is 10.0.4.101 but when i trie to connect from 10.40.0.11 to 10.10.0.16, same error "crendetials didn't work"

On wireshark :
[image]

on event viewer :
[image]

- id event 143, socket TCP error 64
- id event 226 error code 0x80070040
- id event 103 reason 4407

what i ve done :

- sfc /scannow >> no errors
- dism check/scan/restore health >> no errors
- netsh interface ipv4 set subinterface "Ethernet0" mtu=1452
  store=persistent >> no change
- deleted rds selfsigned certificate
- restarted rds services
- Test-NetConnection -ComputerName 10.10.0.16 -CommonTCPPort "RDP"
  -InformationLevel "Detailed" >> all ok
- GPOs to disable ModuleRemoteFX.
- Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal
  Server\ DWORD: MaxOutstandingConnections VALUE: 10000

And still no luck.
Any advice?

**EDIT :**

- As local admin, i can connect.
- I also can connect when i m on 10.10.4.0 network.

**EDIT2 and 3 :**

- unjoin and rejoin domain: OK >> but after another reboot KO.

Thanks.